# Load kernel module module2.ko which is dependent on module1.ko before kernel module module1.ko

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

> How can i load module2.ko in kernel before module1.ko. module2.ko is
> dependent on module1.ko, because module1.ko is having the definition
> of function and module2.ko have its calling. I have inserted a condition in module2.c to check if the module1 is loaded in kernel or not. If its loaded it would perform the function, otherwise it should print an error message. I have mentioned my code below.

module1.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>     /* Needed by all modules */ 
#include <linux/kernel.h>     /* Needed for KERN_INFO */ 
#include <linux/init.h>       /* Needed for the macros */ 
#include <linux/fs.h>         // Needed by filp
#include <asm/uaccess.h> 

MODULE_LICENSE("Test");
int mul(void) 
{
    printk("Running module1.c\n"); 
    int a=2,b=620;
    int ans = 0;
    ans = a * b; 
    printk("The value sent to module1.c = %d\n", ans); 
    return ans; 
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(mul);


static int start(void) 
{
    return 0;
} 



static void end(void) 
{ 
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye.\n");
} 

module_init(start); 
module_exit(end);
```

module2.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>     /* Needed by all modules */ 
#include <linux/kernel.h>     /* Needed for KERN_INFO */ 
#include <linux/init.h>       /* Needed for the macros */ 
#include <linux/fs.h>         // Needed by filp


MODULE_LICENSE("Test"); 
MODULE_AUTHOR("Ali"); 
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Making two dependent Modules");  
MODULE_VERSION("0.1"); 
  
void display(void){
    printk("Running module2.c\n");
}
static int hello_start(void) 
{
    int res = 0;
    display();
    int fd;
    fd = filp_open("/sys/module/module1", O_RDONLY, 0);
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is flag %d\n",fd);
    if(fd > 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Module not exists in Kernel!!.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        extern int mul(void);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Module exists in Kernel!!.\n");
        printk(KERN_ALERT"The value recieved from module1.c = %d\n", res=mul());
    }
        
    return 0;
} 
  
static void hello_end(void) 
{ 
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye123.\n"); 
} 
  
module_init(hello_start); 
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m = module1.o module2.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```